# Como usar os comando do Git sem sudo?

Tags: git

Sempre que preciso usar alguns comandos como git pull, git stash, aparece uma mensagem que não foi possível realizar a operação pelo fato da permissão não ser suficiente. Como faço para que não precise usar o sudo?

Comment: O usuário que você está usando não tem permissão para alterar as pastas que esses comandos estão tentando alterar. Em que pasta estão os seus arquivos? Tente colocar em uma pasta do usuário.

Comment: tentou dar o comando "sudo -s" e a senha de admin.. é isso que precisa ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Você tem duas opções:

1) Fazer o checkout como outro usuário. ("git checkout ...").

2) Alterar a permissão em todo o projeto para que o usuário que você quer possa utilizar o sistema de arquivos. (chown -R)

Comment: Realmente isso, a segunda opção deu certíssimo!! Estou trabalhando em uma máquina homologada e com o docker, assim o docker setou o meu usuário no container com id de usuário 1000, mas a minha maquina tem um id gerado pela empresa, quando executava os comandos nao tinha permissao mesmo... Obrigado!!